# Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context

Tags: product-view

i am trying this below code, i am getting error `Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context` :  at line : `if ($sellerProductInfo->getSize() = 0) {`

this is code i tried in view.phtml :

```
$sellerProductInfo = $this->getSellerProductInfo($productowner['userid']);

    if ($sellerProductInfo->getSize() = 0) {
    $rowsocial= Mage::getModel('marketplace/userprofile')->getPartnerProfileById($productowner['userid']);
    } else {
     $sellersProductInfo = $this->getSellerProductInfo();
     if ($sellersProductInfo->getSize() > 0) {
       $sellerId = $sellersProductInfo->getFirstItem()->getSellerId();
       $rowsocial = Mage::getModel('marketplace/userprofile')->getPartnerProfileById($sellerId);
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a simple syntax error :)

`if ($sellerProductInfo->getSize() = 0) {` should be '==' instead of '='.

Comment: thanks, its worked. now i am getting this error : `Fatal error: Call to a member function getSize() on a non-object in` line : `if ($sellerProductInfo->getSize() == 0) {`

Comment: Sounds like `$this->getSellerProductInfo()` is returning something other than an object, perhaps a null or something you'll need to check for and handle.